# Circuit testbench nailbed: how to test the pots?

Tags: pcb, testing, production-testing

Imagine I make an analog circuit, lets say a guitar pedal circuit (in a PCB of course).

How can I test (automatically if possible) the potentiometers functionality, when testing in a nailbed testbench ?

Comment: First step: think about how you would test it **manually**. Second step: think about how the same (electrical part of the) measurement could be performed **without human intervention** (but connecting the wires and mounting the PCB is still done by a human).

Comment: In reasonable quantities a human turns the knob while test equipment monitors circuit characteristics.  In __very__ large volume automated production a robot or other automation jig will turn the knob for you.